# Reading parameters from External file - C#

Tags: c#, readfile

I am writing an application using C# and I would like to read some parameters from an external file like for example a text file. The parameters will be saved in the file in the form of

```
parA = 5
parB = hello
etc
```

Can you pleas suggest a way how I can do this?

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Opening & reading the file? Parsing the lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know its not what you specifically asked, but if you have the choice I would go with an XML Application config.

There's plenty of resources on it but here's a fairly straight forward example:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dolson/XMLConfigInWinForms11262005014845AM/XMLConfigInWinForms.aspx

Comment: @Mouthpiec I would agree - In my opinion not only are you showing you can do the question but you are demonstrating that you are thinking about design choices too

Answer (score 8):

```
var settings = 
     from line in File.ReadAllLines("params.txt")
     let parameters = line.Split('=')
     select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(parameters[0], parameters[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Read each line and split it at the first occurrence of `"="`.

Comment: I would say split at the first occurrence of " = ", or trim the results of the array.

Comment: @Matt: depending on whether the whitespace there is significant. But yes, I kinda assumed that the elements would be trimmed, then. But the question itself was too obvious already, actually.